# Angular Material dropdown using md-select and md-option doesn't display

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I was able to successfully create dropdown picker by designing stand-alone page using md-select/md-option as mentioned below, However when i use this in my app it throws an error and I don't see dropdown but just the label.

html Page:

```
<form name="pForm" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="pController" class="container-fluid" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" aria-label="ShowHideAccountant">  
        <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label>Area Picker :  </label>
            <md-select ng-model="widgetType" >
            <md-option ng-value="t.title" data-ng-repeat="t in widget">{{ t.title }}</md-option>
            </md-select>

        <label>Business Impact :  </label>
            <md-select ng-model="businessImpactType" >
            <md-option ng-value="option.name" data-ng-repeat="option in businessImpact">{{option.name}}</md-option>
            </md-select>   
        </div>   
</form>
```

javascript:

```
myApp.controller('pController', function($scope) {
  $scope.widget = [{
    "id": "line",
    "title": "Line"
  }, {
    "id": "spline",
    "title": "Smooth line"
  }, {
    "id": "area",
    "title": "Area"
  }, {
    "id": "areaspline",
    "title": "Smooth area"
  }];

  //init
  $scope.widgetType = 'Line';

$scope.businessImpactType = 'CAMERA';

});
```

working:
(inspected on Line element )

```
<md-select data-brackets-id="789" ng-model="widgetType" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid md-default-theme" tabindex="0" role="combobox" id="select_003" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="select_label_001" aria-invalid="false">
    <md-select-label class="md-select-label " id="select_label_001">
        <span class="ng-binding">Line</span>
        <span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true">
        </span>
    </md-select-label>
</md-select>
```

[image]

non-working / error:
When i use the same code in my existing app the console throws an error and i don't see dropdown option.

[image]

```
    ARIA: Attribute " aria-label ", required for accessibility, is missing on node: 
<md-select ng-model="widgetType" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" id="select_3" aria-invalid="false">
    <md-select-value class="md-select-value md-select-placeholder" id="select_value_label_0">
        <span></span>
        <span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </md-select-value>
</md-select>
```

Comment: .. It could be useful if you post the error you're receiving!

Comment: @slackmart: non-working / error section has error details.

Comment: 1st dropdown works fine while 2nd dropdown is using a string so it won't display any option since there are none available.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a collection named `businessImpact` in your `controller` to make your code work.

As far as the error you said, its a Warning! and not an error. This should not bother. It is about setting an attribute called `aria-label` on `md-select` node.

I have created working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mrk_m/vkuvyxjc/5/

To get more info about warning see this [How do I disable ngAria in ngMaterial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666742/how-do-i-disable-ngaria-in-ngmaterial) .

and

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3441